# how system verilog program module avoids timing issues ?

Tags: system-verilog

why exactly the program module concept came into picture ? I read in one book that it is to avoid the timing violations. How  ?

Any suggestions or help is highly appreciated.

Thank You 
Sam

Comment: Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . try to give a detailed information about your question. What issue your facing? , where your blocking? , what you tried so far? like the way you have to give.

Comment: timing issues have nothing to do with modules.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a question like this is considered to broad and opinionated for SO. But since I was directly involved in the development and standardization of SystemVerilog, I can present a few facts from an [article](http://go.mentor.com/programblocks) I wrote about it.

Program blocks came directly from a [donation of the Vera language to SystemVerilog](http://www.design-reuse.com/news/?id=3383&print=yes) by Synopsys , and try to mimic the scheduling semantics that a PLI application has interacting with a Verilog simulator.

A `program` block's original purpose in SystemVerilog was to avoid race conditions (not timing violations) between sampling and driving signals between the DUT and the Testbench. It also controlled starting and termination of the "*test*".

Since its introduction, a number of other features within SystemVerilog have subsumed the need for `program` blocks as I explain in my [article](http://go.mentor.com/programblocks).